# Does fried food cause gastritis and other gastrointestinal tract illnesses?

Tags: nutrition, gastroenterology

And why exactly fried food is bad for heath? Simply because of the crust scratching the stomach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many reasons why fried food can be harmful. The chief reason is related to the oil content in these foodstuffs.

1. It has high oil content which may not be good if consumed in large amounts. Fried food cannot be tolerated by people who have undergone gall bladder removal.
2. Oils are heated at high temeperatures and in many fried-food outlets (or in general practice), reheated many times. This leads to some chemical reactions, some of which include cracking of the hydrocarbon chains and isomerization. These reactions can produce carcinogenic substances ([Srivastava et al. 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0007114510002229)).
3. Oil vapours from these food can also cause respiratory distress in some people, especially asthmatics.

Comment: So it just comes to a lot of fats plus carcinogens? But the fats from the oil are just as bad in salads, right? Or is the fried oil especcially bad if carcinogens excluded?

Comment: @German the process of heating of oils at high temperature during frying causes production of carcinogens. You also don't use a lot of oils in salads (and usually use olive oil which is better than some oils used for frying)

Comment: Wait, but there are ways to fry without oil. Then what? Does it make frying healthy if you get rid of oil?

Comment: @German I am not aware of any way of frying without oil. [Frying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frying) essentially involves the usage of oil.

Comment: I meen somehow using skillet without oil and without much water. How would you call it?

Comment: @German - That is broiling, or pan broiling.